# Retrieve Data from API using C#

Tags: c#, xml, api

I would like to retrieve this data inside of a class in c# based on a URL address "http://sporing.bring.no/sporing.xml?q=TESTPACKAGE-AT-PICKUPPOINT".

Unfortunately, you cannot use "XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("");" to retrieve the data because the url address is not a xml file.

What sourcecode in C# do I need in order to retrieve the data of the xml based on the URL address "http://sporing.bring.no/sporing.xml?q=TESTPACKAGE-AT-PICKUPPOINT"?

Thanks!

Comment: you have to download it using a webclient.

Comment: `the data because the url address is not a xml file` Huh? That is an XML file.  That works fine.

Comment: Just use `WebClient.DownloadFile` to download it into a string, then use `XDocument.Parse()` to load it from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://sporing.bring.no/sporing.xml?q=TESTPACKAGE-AT-PICKUPPOINT"));
```

This will probably solve your problem.