# C# code to retrieve xml data

Tags: c#, xml, api, visual-studio-2013

Based on the this [sourcecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676462/retrieve-data-from-api-using-c-sharp) I'm not able to retrieve the data from the [API](http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/matchning?lanid=1&kommunid=180&yrkesid=2419&1&antalrader=10000) into `XDocument`.

I retrieve the error message

> {"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."}

Question:
I don't know what to do?

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(new
WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/matchning?lanid=1&kommunid=180&yrkesid=2419&1&antalrader=10000"));
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Some more information would help.

Comment: I want to retrieve that data that is from the link into the variable xml

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623664/bad-request-400-protocol-error-on-a-valid-url-webclient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send HTTP headers:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", " en-US");
    client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");

    XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(client.DownloadString("http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/matchning?lanid=1&kommunid=180&yrkesid=2419&1&antalrader=10000"));
}
```

Comment: The server is returning XML, and that is the format that the OP is expecting. So I would change the Accept header to just `"application/xml"`.

Comment: The code is working but I retrieve another eroror message "{System.Xml.XmlException} {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}". I need to add a new message in Stackoverflow. Thank you for your help!