# Error message in XML and API with C# Code

Tags: c#, xml, api, visual-studio-2013

Based on this code below from previous [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683402/c-sharp-code-to-retrieve-xml-data):

```
 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
 {
     client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", " en-US");
     client.Headers.Add("Accept", " text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
     client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");

     XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(client.DownloadString("http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/matchning?lanid=1&kommunid=180&yrkesid=2419&1&antalrader=10000"));
 }
```

I retrieve a error message

> {System.Xml.XmlException} {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}

I tried solving it but I cannot find a solution to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually getting a json, change the following:

```
client.Headers.Add("Accept", " text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
```

to

```
client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
```